# azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions vs triggered Webjob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Azure offers the posability to create a "Triggered" WebJob which e.g. schedules every day. 
[image: Add Triggered WebJob]

Furthermore, there is the azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions(https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) which offers the possibility to create a TimerTrigger:

```
public static void TimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:00:30")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Timer job fired!");
}
```

Both things do exactly the same? Why is this in the SDK, the azure solution doesn't need a continous running job and thus is more efficient.

Comment: For more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk

Comment: Any updates? Have you solved your issue?

Comment: It's not really an issue, I just want to know why there are different ways for the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[TimerTrigger]` allows you to schedule an individual function within a Continuous WebJob. You can then have multiple functions within the WebJob with different schedules.

CRON expressions and Azure Scheduler will always run an entire WebJob.

Comment: If there are multiple functions within the WebJob, how can they be debugged separately? I.e. when the project starts up, it immediately runs through `Program.Main` and then triggers all TimerTrigger functions within `Functions.cs`. Is it possible to only debug these functions one at a time?

Comment: You should make a new question for that.